# How to handle first questions/answers by new users

Tags: discussion

There's a new answer to this question about [New Horizons](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/9277/will-the-pluto-flyby-by-new-horizons-be-broadcast-online). The answer is brief and unsupported by references, so half an hour after it was posted, it's already attracting downvotes and Delete votes.

Now, this is the first answer by a new user of this site. Shouldn't we give newcomers a bit more time to improve their answer before it's deleted?

I'm worried the negative reaction will discourage new users, when we should be inviting them to participate. I've seen this pattern a few times now: new user posts something not-fantastic but salvageable, post gets deleted immediately, user is never seen again.

Comment: I agree with you in principle, but that particular answer is not only brief, but also completely incorrect. Shouldn't it be down voted for that, and not the fact that it's poorly formatted and badly worded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Now, this is the first answer by a new user of this site. Shouldn't we
>   give newcomers a bit more time to improve their answer before it's
>   deleted?

Not in this case, where the answer took a few seconds to write, and there's no content in it worth preserving that wouldn't be easy enough to reproduce (literally just: *"yes, they will be it says on the nasa site"*), if its author wants to start again. Note that the contributor in question [isn't even registered with the site](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/10283/josh?tab=profile) and contribution shows no regard for quality, so there's not much chance that will occur. I wouldn't mind being pleasantly surprised, but it does look like a *flyby post* (no pun intended).

So, depending on your [site privileges](https://space.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), down-vote, flag as *low quality* or *not an answer*, vote to delete, add a custom comment or select one that applies from templates in the low quality review queue, and once a moderator sees it, if that doesn't happen before by community vote, it will be deleted. Note that such flags are now *[suppressed](http://modnewsletter.stackexchange.com/2015/02/february-2015-newsletter/#flagsuppress)* in moderator queue so the community has the time to react without moderator's intervention.

Additionally, if you notice that some questions attract many low quality (or even spam and [spam seeds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256709/what-is-a-spam-seed)) and subsequently deleted contributions, please raise a custom flag with request that the question is protected to prevent future low quality answers. And high reputation members ([3,500 points on beta sites](https://space.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)) can protect questions themselves without moderator's intervention.

Answer (score 0):

As a new user I'm learning that there is a certain way to answer a question. I give an answer and back up my answer with some discussion. When doing that I am told that part of my answer didn't answer the question, or that I should have asked another question. I'm trying.

Comment: Have you checked out the tour: https://space.stackexchange.com/tour and the help: https://space.stackexchange.com/help  Those can tell you a lot about how the site works.